# Search string for content

Tags: string, file, search, google-apps-script

I seem to be missing basic string operations in Google script.

How can I search for stringA in stringB ?

I'm searching the Description field, in an array of files (doclist.find) for specific keywords.

Maybe there is another way of doing this, I've tried to use regexp or underscoregs._find but hav'nt made it work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
var index = stringB.indexOf(stringA);
```

It returns -1 if stringA is not found and the position of stringA within stringB if found. 
For all String operations, the JavaScript specification holds good. 
[Try w3schools for help](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)